# Is Monogame still worth using in 2018

Tags: game-engine, monogame

I know there are a lot of posts dealing the question out there but some years passed now.

I started working with Unity and want to start developing 2D games. Unity is a pretty good engine and is able to deal with 2D but obviously this game engine is designed for 3D.

Other engines or Frameworks may use scripting languages but I want to use C# as my main language. I know Godot supports C# but it focuses on GDScript.

I just read about Monogame and want to know if it is still worth using or outdated. By saying outdated I mean it is not maintained anymore or not many people use it anymore.

Comment: I don't see why not. Monogame is still in development and there are also still games made with it, one notable example is Celeste. It's only difficult to say if it's recommended as a beginner. since there's more code than interface as far I can remember. But you'll learn how to code quicker that way.

Answer (score 5):

It is maintained and the community is pretty active.
For me, it is the optimal Framework for 2D games. You surely have to make some Things on your own while e.g. Unity takes care of them for you, but you have full control and you can do whatever you want.

And - as you said - Unity is designed for 3D games and therefore creating quite a lot Overhead when building 2D games.

Since the Framework is kinda low level, even if they would stop development next year, you would be able to use it for quite a long time.